# Why does increasing distance from the double slit in Young's experiment increase the separation between the fringe pattern?

Tags: waves, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

I don't understand what equation deals with this.

Comment: Related (and may be be a possible dupe): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203979/why-does-moving-the-source-slit-closer-to-the-double-slit-plane-decrease-the-sha and links therein.

Answer (score 4):

As a diagram screen $A$ is closer than screen $B$ and so the fringes are closer  on screen $A$:

[image]

Fringe separation $\Delta x = \dfrac {\lambda \; D}{d}$ where $d$ is the slit separation, $\lambda$ is the wavelength of light and $D$ the distance from the slits to the screen.