# The function of the pinhole in the double slit experiment

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, double-slit-experiment

Even with incoherent light from the sun and not having any laser, Young achieves a result by reducing the incident light to a point-like source. This makes sense because a wider beam works like many pinholes. Each hole creates its own intensity distribution behind slits and there are no fringes visible. A further explanation of the pinhole highlights that the pinhole makes incoherent light coherent.

But how a pinhole makes light from a thermic source - for example from a [sodium-vapor lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-vapor_lamp) - coherent?

Furthermore, does the light behind a hole then have the same properties as laser light?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/331672/104696) help?

Answer (score 2):

The pin hole serves to make the light spatially coherent:all wave vectors point in the same direction. To turn it into laser light it must also be temporally coherent : all frequencies are the same. The intrinsic bandwidth of the light coming from a sodium source should be much larger than that of a laser, as a high quality factor resonance cavity is missing.

Comment: Not sure about the bandwidths. The bandwidth of a laserpointer is around 1 nm or more, the bandwidth of a sodium-vapor lamp has two spectral lines very close together at 589.0 and 589.6 nm, which is less as from the laser.

Comment: Is that the intrinsic bandwidth?

Comment: That  I tried to find out. About the sodium lamp see Wikipedia. About the laser diode what do you know?

Comment: A German source https://www.itwissen.info/Laserdiode-laser-diode-LD.html says, that “Die spektrale Breite mit der Laserdioden ihr Licht aussenden, beträgt nur 1 nm, im Falle des Distributed Feedback Lasers (DFB) ist sie sogar nur 0,1 nm.“ (The spectral width with which laser diodes emit their light is only 1 nm, in the case of the Distributed Feedback Laser (DFB) it is only 0.1 nm.)

Comment: Following the link to the article on DFB lasers I read "einer geringeren chromatischen Dispersion innerhalb der Monomodefaser nieder". So 1 nm is the inhomogeneous linewidth and the homogeneous linewidth is smaller than 0.1 nm.

Comment: Perhaps a laser pointer will not reach such characteristics? But works fine in a slit experiment?

Comment: Lasers have maximal spatial coherence. This you can only achieve with a sodium source at great loss of efficiency.