# Single slit then double slit

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

I am quite aware of what the intensity patterns will be on the screen for a single slit and a double slit experiment. However I have a hard time grasping the consequence of the intensity patterns when a source of light goes through a single slit first and then a double slit. Could anyone kindly clarify this for me?

Comment: Related - [Why must the single slit in a double slit experiment be narrow?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331572/104696)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have in mind that for an interference pattern to show on the screen during a double-slit experiment, you need a **coherent source of light**. If you use a high coherence laser, you can directly illuminate the double-slit; but if you lack a coherent source of light you first need to make one. That's when the first slit becomes useful as it makes light *spatially coherent*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the source is coherent in nature,  the intensity of the interference pattern will be same as that of a ' only ' double slit interference and ' a single slit and then double slit ' interference. This is so because the single slit acts again as a new source of light with same intensity, hence producing same intensity fringes as that of the 'only' double slit experiment.