# How does an interference pattern change when the width of a single slit is widen?

Tags: optics, interference, diffraction

It came about when discussing Young's double slit experiment, that in order to get a double slit interference pattern during his time, he had to first place a single slit screen in front of his double slit screen.

I'm curious to know why the single slit screen is important and what happens when you vary the width of the single slit, how does it effects the outcome of the double slit interference pattern?

I'm a bit confused on why increasing the width of the single slit, the central maximum is more narrower than if you decrease the width of the single slit the central maximum is wider.

Comment: At the time of Young it was the only way to get coherent electromagnetic waves, make a point source, which by construction lets only [coherent light][1] appear. The single slit has that function in two dimensions.  This uses plane waves , but might help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/slits.html

Comment: Duplicate? [Why must the single slit in a double slit experiment be narrow?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/331572/why-must-the-single-slit-in-a-double-slit-experiment-be-narrow/331672#331672)